# Custom Portfolio String

Tags: custom-post-types, php, query-string

I have a field on my portfolio admin page which shows the url when the user write a url(obviosly).

I want to when the user write in the field, elements appear along with it. And if the field is empty dont shows anything.

The code that shows what the user is writing in this field is:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_url', TRUE);?>
```

I tried:

```
<?php if (strpos($post->ID,'_url') !== true) {   ?>

        [CONTENT] <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_url', TRUE); ?> [/CONTENT]

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you have [CONTENT] in your code?

Comment: is the rest of content like <p> <a href> and other codes

Comment: i want if the custom metabox in my admin is empty, nothing below "if" will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a if statement using the `get_post_meta` like this

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_url', true)){?>

 <p> Display some stuff.</p>

<?php } ?>
```

There is an example here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: Sorry, Had a typo see my edit.